# html audio cannot find file after changing source through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have this audio element in my .html file:

> ```
> <audio id ="captcha">
>       <source id = "capt_wav" src = "doghouse.wav" type = "audio/wav" >
> </audio>
> ```

and it plays the audio. Now I need to change the src attribute dynamically using jQuery. 
I then set the original html audio to have no source (src = "") and I use this jQuery code to set the source:

> ```
>   $('#capt_wav').attr('src',"doghouse.wav");
> ```

This actually changes the source, as I can see from the console:

BEFORE:

> ```
> <source id="capt_wav" src="" type="audio/wav">
> ```

AFTER:

> ```
> <source id="capt_wav" src="doghouse.wav" type="audio/wav">
> ```

but in this case it doesn't play the audio, giving me the errors:

> Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed. @ file:///home/index.html
>
> All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. @ file:///home/index.html

The file is in the folder, any idea why it doesn't work? The html (its source) is identical in both cases.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of the src attribute after you change the source file?

Comment: yes, that's what you see in the "AFTER". I printed the console output before and after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#capt_wav").attr("src", "doghouse.wav").detach().appendTo("#captcha");
```

It seems the browser only plays the file when the element is added, not when it is just modified.