# How to change audio source for Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, html5-audio

I use the following code to change source of HTML5 audio element:

```
$('#mp3').attr('src', url); // please note that remote URL is used
$("#audio").load();
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" class="hidden">
  <source type="audio/mpeg" id="mp3">
</audio>
```

It works well in Google Chrome, Safari, IE. But Firefox 34 returns the following error:

```
<source> element has no "src" attribute. Media resource load failed.
```

What is wrong here?

**Upd**. I verify if it works by waiting for `canplaythrough` event to be called. Probably this is the problem?

I've tried also to delete the element and add it again, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#audio").empty();
$("<source>").attr("src", url).attr("type", "audio/mpeg").appendTo("#audio");
$("#audio").load();
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300640/html-audio-cannot-find-file-after-changing-source-through-jquery

Comment: @Nico, thanks, but it helped, but only once - audio started to play, but it doesn't work any more. Will try to investigate what happened.

Comment: @Nico, that approach works only if I opened (=downloaded) file manually before.

Comment: When are you running the above code? After the dom is ready?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, yes. Once user chooses the audio from the select element.

Answer (score 1):

I've found two problems with the code I used with regards to Firefox:

1) `src` attribute change. As @Nico mentioned, Firefox doesn't work properly with direct `src` value change, so I had to re-create source element:

```
$("#audio").empty();
$("<source>").attr("src", url).attr("type", "audio/mpeg").attr("id", "mp3").appendTo("#audio");
$("#audio").load();
```

2) once `src` value is changed, Firefox doesn't start to load audio (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430919/604388)), so `canplaythrough` is never called. Addition of `preload="auto"` helped:

```
<audio id="audio" class="hidden" preload="auto">
  <source type="audio/mpeg" id="mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/vz330koy/3/)